# Modem is Not Seeing Router -- Breaks port forward

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a baffling issue.
I have a remote client site using Spectrum Business as their ISP, with a static WAN IP.
Currently using some Ubee modem, don't know the model. The Ubee modem is in bridge mode (according to spectrum) and connected to my Ubiquiti UniFi Security Gateway. the USG is set to Static IP, and using the WAN IP and WAN Router given by Spectrum. The LAN CIDR range is 10.130.0.1/24, USG is at 10.130.0.1

Here's where it gets confusing. I cannot get port forwarding to work. Somehow, port 22 is working (as set), but no other port I forward works. (eg. 80, 443, 1194)
Asked the guys at Spectrum to take a look, and they said that the Modem is seeing 1 LAN client: 10.130.0.84 NOT 10.130.0.1

We reset the Modem and dropped a new config onto it and still resolves only to that LAN client. Oddly, port 22 successfully forwards to x.x.x.110 as I had set. Every client on the network has full internet access. Yet any additional port forward rules I define do not get passed.

Running a tracreroute on port 22 terminates at the correct node after 17 hops, however, any other forwarded port (forwarded to the same *110 machine) Times Out through Hops 17 - 30 with no tangible result.

Spectrum, of course, is no help and is convinced the issue is the fault of the Ubiquiti USG, however I am not so convinced. BTW, Spectrum does not allow clients access to their modem, so I literally cannot do anything there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance you can connect a computer directly to the modem, configure it with the static IP from the ISP, then use something like http://canyouseeme.org and test against some open ports on the computer? This would effectively rule in or out the USG as your problem.

Comment: That would be something to try but I am in a separate state from the client site so I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. It wasn't as baffling as it was stupid.

I was setting up multiple services atonce and long story short ran some netstat commands and found some ports were not listening, despite the services running without noticeable error.

I blew away my apache config and started fresh and began to work. SO I wondered if I f--d up the configs for my other services and sure enough I did. So once I fixed each service, everything began to work. So a coincidence of bad configs, running services, and spectrums incompetence led me through loops. Luckily the nice guys over at the Ubiquiti Forums gave me some hints to tcpdump the lan and wan ports on the USG. Once I traced the failures, I realized my mistakes.

HOWEVER -- This does not solve the issue of the random LAN client appearing on the Modem's port rather than the IP of the Router. That is still a head scratcher

Answer (score -1):

> Running a tracreroute on port 22 terminates at the correct node after 17 hops, however, any other forwarded port (forwarded to the same *110 machine) Times Out through Hops 17 - 30 with no tangible result.

It's not by any chance hitting *110 on port whatever, but that machine dropping packets on that port? Just a basic check.

Also rule out that traffic is infact getting to your gateway. Can you mirror the link between the gateway and modem on the switch by any chance and sniff it?

If it's not even getting from the modem to gateway, then the issue is with the modem.

Comment: Forgive me, I am unsure how to effectively mirror the port on the USG. And traffic is not being dropped at the *110 machine, for testing I completely disabled the firewall on the machine. So the thing is wide open right now. Local traffic on the LAN works fine, all ports and services work as expected.